# Setting src for image inside an li selected using .eq?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the `src` of of the first image in the first `li` to the combination of two variables each containing a string.
I tried using:

```
    $( "li" ).eq(0, function(){
    $("img").eq(0).attr("src", eval(id+thumbnail));
   });
```

I also tried this:

```
$( ".mainlist li:nth-child(0)", function(){
$("img:eq( 0 )").attr("src", eval(id+thumbnail));
});
```

but it does not work.

Edit:
After a few hours of trying I got this to work:

```
$( "ul.mainlist li:nth-child(1)", function(){
$("img:eq( 0 )").attr("src", id+thumbnail);
});
});
```

however it only works on the first image of the page and not the first image inside the first `li` in the `mainlist ul`.

Comment: That's not what `eval()` is for. It's probably returning either 0 or true. How's `$("img").eq(0).attr("src", \`${id}${thumbnail}\` );` work for ya? PS: [Template literals are neat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: yes! i just got **$("img:eq( 0 )").attr("src", id+thumbnail);** to work but it only works for the first image on the page

Comment: That's because of the eq(0), it throws away all but the first result/item.

Comment: so would there be any way to select the first image in the first li of the page and then set its src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is not qualifying the `img`, so it does - as you found - select the first image on the page. To find the first image inside the `li`, use [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the `img` elements below the `li` element and [`.first`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to select the first image:

```
$('ul.mainlist li:nth-child(0)').find('img').first().attr("src", id+thumbnail);
```

Comment: still affecting the first image on the page :(

Comment: @Jerick120 sorry, hadn't noticed how you were calling the function, so `$(this)` wasn't pointing to the actual `li` element. Are you trying to do this on an event? If not, my edited code should work.